# How do I enable a button once two other buttons have been clicked at least once?

Tags: javascript, html

On a web page I've created, I have four main buttons that the user can interact with: 
- Home: redirects user to website home page
- Twitter: takes user through Twitter authentication process 
- Spotify: takes user through Spotify authentication process
- Next: will redirect user to a new web page

My goal is to enable the "Next" button only after the user has clicked the "Twitter" and "Spotify" at least once.

I have created some JavaScript functions that keep track of how many times the user has clicked the Twitter and Spotify buttons in an attempt to enable the Next button after they've clicked those buttons at least once. The functionality of this is a little wonky and I'm not sure why. It seems that the function isn't properly updating the local storage variables I am running which in turn messes up the enable/disable functionally of the Next button.

Here is the most updated version of the HTML for my web page:

```js
// Enable Build Playlist Button
function enableBuildButton() {

  if (localStorage.twitToggleCount && localStorage.spotToggleCount) {

    var spotifyToggle = localStorage.getItem("twitToggleCount");
    var twitterToggle = localStorage.getItem("spotToggleCount");

    if (spotifyToggle && twitterToggle >= 1) {

      document.getElementById("build_playlist").disabled = false;
    }
  }
}

//Twitter Button Toggle
function clickToggleTwitter() {

  var twitToggle = document.getElementById("auth_twitter");

  if (localStorage.twitToggleCount) { // Retrieve and update toggle count 

    var currVal = localStorage.getItem("twitToggleCount");
    var updVal = +currVal + 1;

    twitToggle.setAttribute("data-twit-toggle", updVal);
    localStorage.setItem("twitToggleCount", updVal);


  } else { // Set and update toggle count 

    var currVal = twitToggle.getAttribute("data-twit-toggle");
    var updVal = +currVal + 1;

    localStorage.setItem("twitToggleCount", updVal);
    twitToggle.setAttribute("data-twit-toggle", updVal);
  }

  alert(localStorage.twitToggleCount);
}

// Spotify Button Toggle
function clickToggleSpotify() {

  var spotToggle = document.getElementById("auth_spotify");

  if (localStorage.spotToggleCount) { // Retrieve and update toggle count 

    var currVal = localStorage.getItem("spotToggleCount");
    var updVal = +currVal + 1;

    spotToggle.setAttribute("data-spot-toggle", updVal);
    localStorage.setItem("spotToggleCount", updVal);


  } else { // Set and update toggle count 

    var currVal = spotToggle.getAttribute("data-spot-toggle");
    var updVal = +currVal + 1;

    localStorage.setItem("spotToggleCount", updVal);
    spotToggle.setAttribute("data-spot-toggle", updVal);
  }

  alert(localStorage.spotToggleCount);

}

// Delete all local storage variables (and or data)
function clearLocalStorage() {
  localStorage.clear();
  alert(localStorage.spotToggleCount);
  alert(localStorage.twitToggleCount);
}

//Onclick event to redirect to build playlist web page
function navigateToBuildPlaylist() {
  window.location = "http://..../build"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title> Your Twitter Playlist </title>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Authentication</h1>

  <p>
    In order to create "Your Twitter Playlist", the application needs access to your Spotify and Twitter accounts.
  </p>

  <button type="button" id="home"> 
       <a href="http://.../"> Home </a> 
    </button>

  <button type="button" id="auth_twitter" data-twit-toggle="0" onclick="clickToggleTwitter();enableBuildButton()">  
        <a href="http://.../auth/twitter"> Twitter </a> 
    </button>

  <button type="button" id="auth_spotify" data-spot-toggle="0" onclick="clickToggleSpotify();enableBuildButton()">
        <a href="http://.../auth/spotify"> Spotify </a> 
    </button>

  <button type="button" id="build_playlist" disabled="true" onclick="enableBuildButton();navigateToBuildPlaylist();clearLocalStorage();">
        Next
    </button>

</body>

<footer>

  <p>Designed & Built by Mikal Hayden-Gates.</p>

  <p>Copyright © 2019 Your Twitter Playlist. All Rights Reserved.</p>

</footer>

</html>
```

I expect the Next button to be enabled once I click the "Twitter" and "Spotify" button, but it seems to randomly being enabling and disabling itself when the page reloads. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why is this tagged with python?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what the values of twitToggleCount and spotifyToggleCount are after clicking their respective buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue to use anchor tags use `target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"`:

`<a href='/' target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Link</a>`

You are redirecting and thus the script doesn't run

(Alternatively change to buttons and handle the logic in your javascript)

[Working modified CodePen example (with anchor tags)](https://codepen.io/WillWillman/pen/XWWgoKw)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't think the "target" and "rel" attributes are needed in my case but adding the enableBuildButton() to the unload attribute in the body tag and using the nextClick() function seemed to do the trick.